# how do you get onfocus to read from an external js file

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to access a function in my .js file from my html using the "onfocus" attribute, but it doesn't  work. I hate having to write JS inside HTML it makes it cluttered and harder to read/debug later on.

so here is the html code from "JMLessons.html":

```
*<input type="text" required="required" id="pFirstName" name="pFirstName1" placeholder="Required" maxlength=35 minlength=1 onfocusout="pFN1()"></input>
```

so the function I'm trying to call "pFN1()" is in "JMLessons/JMLessons.js"

I have this code in the HTML Head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JMLessons/JMLessons.js"></script>
```

When I copy and paste the function into the html in between the proper "" opening and closing tag and run it in the browser it works, but as soon as I delete it from the browser and try to pull it from the JS file, it breaks it. I even went as far as to copy and paste the function into JS since I thought I might have written it wrong. So is there a way to use onfocus in ".html" and access a function in a separate ".js" file?

Here's the JS Function for reference:

```
function pFN1()
{
    var p1n1 = document.getElementById("pFirstName");
        if (p1n1.value.length === 0 || p1n1.value === " ")
            {
                document.getElementById("pFirstName").className="wrongReq";
                return false;
            }
        if (/\d/.test(p1n1.value))
            {
                document.getElementById("pFirstName").className="warningReq";
                return false;
            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById("pFirstName").className="goodReq";
                return true;
            }                                                
}
```

It changes the border color of the text field based on special conditions to allow the user to know if he/she entered it correctly.

Comment: Is the folder JMLessons in the same folder with JMLessons.html?

Comment: Is  in the script `JMLessons.js` function `pFN1()` wrapped in an `window.onload()` or `$(document).ready()` or something else ?

Comment: scartag- yes it is.
Martin Ernst: no, it's not, can you elaborate on those two things, they're new to me, I literally just started making websites and I decided to dive into the deep end with a lead vest and the inability to swim. I'm making a website for my step father who teaches baseball that needs a form that posts to his email, sends a text, and posts to a pending calendar where he can adjust the schedule to his liking, and then sends out text/emails to those that want lesson reminders, so an extremely easy first website for someone with literally no experience.

Comment: @user3677279 1) put an `@` before the name, then we get the message. 2) Sorry, I can't elaborate in a comment. 3) If both files are in same folder try `<script type="text/javascript" src="JMLessons.js"></script>` (without the leading directory).

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on when you load the js file.

Try to put this code `<script type="text/javascript" src="JMLessons/JMLessons.js"></script>` 
in the `<head>` tag.
If it doesn't work, put the same code in the bottom of the html page.

Comment: See OP's question: `I have this code in the HTML Head section`. And when putting code to bottom `focusout` will throw an error `pFN1 is not defined`.

Comment: So maybe the right thing to do is to load the the js file after the whole page is loaded

Comment: No, the function `pFN1` must be defined **before** the input tag that calls it is parsed.